# How would I PIVOT this table in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to learn complex PIVOT usage in T-SQL however I am really stuck on how I can achieve what I want. I have tried following some articles on the internet - Mainly the MS docs and SQLShack but I'm having no luck at achieving what I am after.

Lets say I have a report in SSRS that builds a table that can see data based on a set of parameters. I want each option in every parameter to have a column that can be counted which I assume it done by pivoting the table.

The issue I'm currently having is that when I preview the report in SSRS, I have to manually add up all the rows that are specific to a condition.

[image]

In this example, lets say I want to know the number of all lessons that were DNA'd. From the image , I would have to add up the 3rd and 6th row for the total number of DNA.

Instead of having totals by row, I want totals by column for each label created in the case statements so it will give me totals.

```
@StartDate AS DATE
, @EndDate AS DATE
, @Car AS VARCHAR(MAX)
, @DriverType AS VARCHAR(MAX)
, @Attendance AS VARCHAR(MAX)
, @LearnerType AS VARCHAR(MAX)

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #AttendanceBreakdown, #Final, #Months

SELECT DISTINCT [YearMonth]
INTO #Months
FROM xxx
WHERE [Date] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate

SELECT [Car_code]
, [Car_code] + ' - ' + S.[Car_name] AS [Car]
, [YearMonth]
, CASE 
    WHEN [attendance] = 'Att' THEN 'Attended' 
    WHEN [attendance] = 'Can' THEN 'Cancelled' 
    WHEN [attendance] = 'Ns' THEN 'No Show' 
END AS [attendance]
, CASE 
    WHEN [driver_type] = 'L' THEN 'Learning'
    WHEN [driver_type] = 'M' THEN 'Matured'
    WHEN [driver_type] = 'F' THEN 'First'
    WHEN [driver_type] = 'C' THEN 'Experienced'
END AS [driver_type]
, CASE 
    WHEN [learner_type] = 'N' THEN 'New' 
    WHEN [learner_type] = 'C' THEN 'Current' 
END AS [learner_type]
INTO #AttendanceBreakdown
FROM [xxx]
LEFT JOIN [xxx].[xxx].[xxx] AS C ON C.[Date] = [xxx]
LEFT JOIN [xxx].[xxx].[xxx] AS S ON S.[car_code] = [car_code]
WHERE [xxx] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
AND [car_code] IN (SELECT [StringLiteral] FROM [xxx].[xxx]. 
[fnSplitStringList] (@Car))
AND [xxx] IS NOT NULL

 SELECT M.[YearMonth]
, [car_code]
, T.[Car]
, [attendance]
, [driver_type]
, [learner_type]
, COUNT(1) AS [TotalLessons]
INTO #Final
FROM #Months AS M
LEFT JOIN #AttendanceBreakdown AS T ON T.[YearMonth] = M.[YearMonth]
WHERE [car_code] IN (SELECT [StringLiteral] FROM [xxx].[xxx]. 
[fnSplitStringList] (@Car))
AND [driver_type] IN (SELECT [StringLiteral] FROM [xxx].[xxx].[fnSplitStringList] 
(@DriverType))
AND [attendance] IN (SELECT [StringLiteral] FROM [xxx].[xxx].[fnSplitStringList] 
(@Attendance))
AND [learner_type] IN (SELECT [StringLiteral] FROM [xxx].[xxx].[fnSplitStringList] 
(@LearnerType))
GROUP BY M.[YearMonth]
, [car_code]
, T.[Car]
, [attendance]
, [driver_type]
, [learner_type]


SELECT F.[YearMonth]
, F.[Car]
, [attendance]
, [driver_type]
, [learner_type]
, [TotalLessons]
FROM #Final AS F
ORDER BY [Car]
, [YearMonth] DESC
, [driver_type]
, [learner_type]
, [attendance]
```

How would I create a Pivot table that can allow me to do this?

Comment: Honestly, if you want to do "complex" pivoting, I strongly recommend using conditional aggregation, rather than the (restrictive) `PIVOT` operator. You have much more control over the different methods of pivoting you want in a single statement (such as `COUNT`s, `SUM` and `MAX` in a single aggregation), as well as the expression used to determine what you are "pivoting" on.

Comment: Sample data and expected results (as text not images) would help immensely

Comment: To echo @Larnu, conditional aggregation is (likely) the way to go with this. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72602978/pivot-conditional-aggregation-data-with-count-and-sum-in-t-sql-query/72607756#72607756) and its answers to see the difference in code